# Is it possible to store matrices in a list or as iterable elements in Python?

Tags: python, list, matrix, indexing, iterable

My Python code generates some matrices (one at a time) through a loop over some index called `i`.

Storing matrices with names like `mat_0, mat_1,..., mat_i` is straightforward but I was wondering if it somehow possible to store matrices like iterable elements like `mat[0], mat[1],...,mat[i]`?

**Note:** The matrices are stored in scipy sparse coo_matrix format.

Edit 1 : The index `i` does not necessarily follow a proper sequence and may loop over some random numbers like `0,2,3,7,...` In that case the matrices have to be stored as `mat[0], mat[2], mat[3], mat[7],...` and so on.

Edit 2: Minimal working code

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, csr_matrix

primesqt = np.array([1.41421356, 1.73205080, 2.23606797, 2.64575131, 3.31662479, 3.60555127, 4.12310562, 4.35889894, 4.79583152, 5.38516480, 5.56776436, 6.08276253, 6.40312423, 6.55743852, 6.85565460, 7.28010988, 7.68114574, 7.81024967, 8.18535277, 8.42614977, 8.54400374, 8.88819441, 9.11043357, 9.43398113, 9.84885780, 10.04987562, 10.14889156, 10.34408043, 10.44030650, 10.63014581, 11.26942766, 11.44552314, 11.70469991, 11.78982612, 12.20655561, 12.28820572, 12.52996408, 12.76714533, 12.92284798, 13.15294643, 13.37908816, 13.45362404, 13.82027496, 13.89244398, 14.03566884, 14.10673597, 14.52583904, 14.93318452, 15.06651917, 15.13274595])

def bg(n, k, min_elem, max_elem):
    allowed = range(max_elem, min_elem-1, -1)

    def helper(n, k, t):
        if k == 0:
            if n == 0:
                yield t
        elif k == 1:
            if n in allowed:
                yield t + (n,)
        elif min_elem * k <= n <= max_elem * k:
            for v in allowed:
                yield from helper(n - v, k - 1, t + (v,))
    return helper(n, k, ())

def BinarySearch(lys, val):  
    first = 0
    last = len(lys)-1
    index = -1
    while (first <= last) and (index == -1):
        mid = (first+last)//2
        if lys[mid] == val:
            index = mid
        else:
            if val<lys[mid]:
                last = mid -1
            else:
                first = mid +1
    return index

m = 4
dim = 16
nmax = 1

a = []
for n in range(0,(nmax*m)+1):
    for x in bg(n, m, 0, nmax):
        a.append(x)

T = np.zeros(dim)
for ii in range(dim):
    for jj in range(m):
        T[ii] += primesqt[jj]*float(a[ii][jj])
ind = np.argsort(T)
T = sorted(T)

all_bs = [0,2,3,7] # i_list
# Evaluate 'mat_ee' for each 'ee' given in the list 'all_bs'
for ee in all_bs:
    row = []
    col = []
    val = []
    for ii in range(m):
        for vv in range(dim):
            Tg = 0
            if a[vv][ii]+1 < nmax+1:
                k = np.copy(a[vv])
                elem = sqrt(float(k[ii]+1.0))+ee
                k[ii] = k[ii]+1
                # Generate tag Tg for elem != 0
                for jj in range(m):
                    Tg += float((primesqt[jj])*k[jj])
                # Search location of non-zero element in sorted T
                location = BinarySearch(T, Tg)
                uu = ind[location]
                row.append(uu)
                col.append(vv)
                val.append(elem)
                mat_ee = (coo_matrix((val, (row, col)), shape=(dim, dim)).tocsr()) # To be stored as mat[0], mat[2], mat[3], mat[7]
    print(mat_ee)
```

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why don't you store the matrices as the values in a dictionary (keyed by a number) if you want random access by some key?

Comment: @OliverW. As I am a absolute beginner in Python I have no idea if it could be done using dictionary. I will give it a try.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please see Edit 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary would allow you to reference an object using an arbitrary (but immutable) object. In your case, you could store the matrices `mat_ee` in each iteration of the outer loop (`for ee in all_bs:`) using that `ee` index:

```py
csr_matrices = {}
for ee in all_bs:
  # your inner loops, all the way to…
  mat_ee = (coo_matrix((val, (row, col)),
                       shape=(dim, dim))
            .tocsr())
  csr_matrices[ee] = mat_ee
```

From that moment, you can access the elements of the dictionaries using the indices you had in `all_bs`:

```py
print(csr_matrices[2])
```

and when you inspect the dictionary, you’ll notice it only contains the keys you specified:

```py
print(csr_matrices.keys())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works as expected. I was wondering if using dictionary will have any performance issues....because I need to update these matrices repeatedly.

Comment: They won’t degrade performance for your usecase: if you compute new matrices, that will be the bottleneck, not their assignment to the keys of the dictionary. Small remark: you should only be concerned with performance once you have working code, that is proven to be correct and that you have profiled. Any attempt to make performance gains without profiling code is sans value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a List of your objects.

```
items_list = list()
for something:
    result = function
    items_list.append(result)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are suggesting to store matrices as objects in a list. But my problem is that the index `i` itself is fetched from another list (say, `list_i`) which is not necessarily in an ordered sequence. So somehow I want to directly map the matrix labels (`mat[i]`) to elements of the `list_i`.